# How do I invest in retirement if I'm planning to leave the US?

Tags: united-states, taxes, retirement, foreign

I'm completely new to investing and know very little about it. I'm about to graduate from college and take a software engineering job that pays very well, leaving me some slack for investing in my retirement.

That being said, I would like to leave the US within 4-8 years. It is my understanding that investing in a 401k, ROTH IRA, and other US-based retirement funds becomes difficult after you leave the country. If I end up moving to several countries over the course of my life, I likely won't be able to invest in any single country's retirement fund as much as I would like.

**How do I maximize my retirement fund(s) if I'm not sure in which country, and when, I will settle down? Is there some sort of trans-national retirement fund or other smart strategy for this sort of situation?**

Comment: Do you plan on returning to the US some decades hence?

Comment: Without knowing where you intend on going, and whether you plan to live there indefinitely, this is not reasonably answerable - a solution that provides a good tax result for a Canadian resident could be meaningless for a UK resident. Without knowing any more, the only answer possible is likely 'keep yourself relatively liquid, in non-tax advantaged accounts that would penalize you if you had to withdraw early'.

Comment: one point, *"Is there some sort of trans-national retirement fund"* - simply, No.

Comment: @RonJohn No, I do not plan to return.

Comment: Of/from/with what country/ies is your citizenship?

Comment: @shoover I am a US citizen and nothing else.

Comment: @RonJohn Giving up US citizenship is a long and arduous process, that often involves the same tax complications and significant personal challenge. To suggest giving up said citizenship to avoid administration of tax filings is... overdoing it, perhaps.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon he's never coming back, which means he -- at best -- prefers other countries to the US.  Why should he then be a citizen of the country he doesn't like?

Comment: What specifically does "leaving me some slack for investing in my retirement" mean to you?  Does it mean "I'm going to contribute **nothing**", or does it mean "I'm going to contribute **only a little**"?

Comment: @RonJohn "He said he's never coming back" Great, I like the conviction! Two problems: (1) Renouncing citizenship of the US would be irrevocable, and (2) OP doesn't have citizenship elsewhere at this point. Good luck dealing with the resulting Statelessness! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statelessness#United_States

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon you'd think a computer programmer would be smart enough to get that foreign citizenship **before** renouncing US citizenship.

Comment: @RonJohn No, *you* were the one who suggested renouncing citizenship, without any caveat, to a likely 20-something college studente. Don't pretend that any flaw in your plan is indication of intellectual failure of the person receiving your advice.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon "`I would like to leave the US within 4-8 years.`" He won't be "a likely 20-something college studente" at that time.  Still, I can see where the comment could mean "do it now".  It doesn't.

Comment: @RonJohn You are giving advice to the OP today, not the OP in 4 years. The important thing now is for the OP to sort out the details, and potentially in light of that to set up tax saving plan that will hopefully defer both US and foreign taxes. Talk of renouncing citizenship is jumping the gun by many years. My advice should stand on its own merit, but at this point I will add that I've practiced in this specific area for many years. What I say is not flippant, it is the result of seeing a lot of heartache for people who have followed impulsive or misguided advice before they came to me.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon as I said, `I can see where the comment could mean "do it now". It doesn't.`  It doesn't mean **now**, it means "once he's settled in whichever foreign country he decides to settle in.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very big subject and, unfortunately, there are no universal answers.  The general advice though is to take advantage of the retirement system where you are resident when you are resident there.  If you have sizeable retirement investments, you should consult an accountant knowledgeable in both tax systems to help you with tax planning before you move to a new country.

### Foreign Retirement Investments and Savings

The details will always depend on your citizenship, where you are a tax resident, and any tax treaties between your country of citizenship and the country where you are a tax resident so no specific advice can be given.

As a US citizen, if you choose to invest in foreign vehicles for retirement while living abroad:

1. Check the relevant tax treaty and consult a knowledgeable tax professional to understand how pensions or retirement savings options like ISAs will be treated from your US tax perspective.  Especially make sure that you do not choose an option that is considered a PFIC unless you have no other choice and/or you know what you're doing and choose to do this.
2. Familiarize yourself with the tax implications of mortgages denominated in foreign currency before investing in real estate.  Specifically, make sure you understand whether paying off the mortgage may result in ordinary gains based on currency exchange rate fluctuations.

Should you choose to return to the US, the relevant tax treaty will also explain how your foreign retirement vehicles will be treated in the US.

### US-based Retirement Investments and Savings

In terms of taking advantage of your US-based retirement vehicles:

If there is a tax treaty in place, you may be able to benefit from and possibly contribute to your US-based retirement vehicles.  If there is not a tax treaty in place or it doesn't cover the specific vehicle you've used (e.g. Roth IRA), you'll need to check with a tax professional knowledgeable about both tax systems.

When the US has a tax treaty with a country, it generally tries to get the other country to apply similar tax treatment to US-based retirement vehicles (401(k), Traditional IRA, Roth IRA, etc) as the US does.  However, not all tax treaties achieve this and some that do are out of date and don't cover things like Roth accounts.  I'm not sure if any cover things like HSAs or 529s.

If your US-based retirement vehicle is covered by a US tax treaty, you can probably expect to withdraw money from it in retirement under similar rules as you would if you were resident in the US.  For Traditional IRAs and 401(k)s, this could mean distributions are taxed as income (at your country of residence's income tax rates).  For Roth IRAs, this could mean distributions are tax free.

In some situations you may also be able to continue contributing to US-based retirement vehicles from your country of residence and still enjoy the expected tax advantages.  For example, you may be able to treat contributions to a traditional IRA as tax-deductible contributions to a "pension".  This gets complicated though when considering the Foreign Earned Income Exclusion (FEIE) as income excluded by the FEIE is not eligible for contribution to an IRA.

Answer (score -2):

The purpose of American retirement plans are to stimulate savings **by deferring US income taxes now** and paying them later.

Since in all likelihood you won't owe US income taxes when you're abroad, **there's no purpose** to deposit money in an IRA.  (401k accounts are irrelevant, since the deposits are handled by your employer, and your Upper Elbonian employer won't expend the effort to run a 401k plan just for you, when you don't owe any US taxes anyway.)

Besides, most countries don't have the concept of the IRA or 401(k) because they have higher government pensions.

Comment: While it is unlikely that a US citizen owes US taxes on *employment income* while living abroad, this is much less certain when talking about investment income. Rules about rates, timing, and sourcing can vary significantly, and there is often a mismatch that results in US taxes owing, without advance planning.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. US citizens working overseas absolutely DO owe taxes to the U.S. From https://www.irs.gov/individuals/international-taxpayers/us-citizens-and-resident-aliens-abroad : "If you are a U.S. citizen or resident alien, the rules for filing income, estate, and gift tax returns and paying estimated tax are generally the same whether you are in the United States or abroad. Your worldwide income is subject to U.S. income tax, regardless of where you reside."

Comment: @shoover the Foreign Earned Income Exclusion limit excludes most income from US taxes, if you're a tax resident of that other country.

Comment: @shoover besides, I wrote, "in all likelihood", which means OP might owe some taxes.

Comment: @shoover lastly, that link you mention says that you must **file** as tax return, not that that you definitely **will owe taxes**.

Comment: @RonJohn Link says income is subject to U.S. income tax regardless of where earned. True, OP may be planning to move to a country where they pay their programmers like U.S. janitors, and thus be below the threshold for paying federal income taxes (i.e. one of the 47%-ers). I'd have to look at the latest SE Salary survey to see where that is.

Comment: @RonJohn FEIE specifically excludes investment income, and OP is asking about how to invest. FTC method of calculation is possible, but tax treaty provisions for investment income are often far more complex, and quirks of timing / country of allocation for specific income types / tax rates within either the US or the other country, often make it so that some amount of US tax is owing. Often, it requires sophisticated tax planning to avoid double-taxation of investment income for a US citizen working abroad.

Comment: An example of how this answer is harmful - most Western democracies with a good US relationship have sufficient tax treaty provisions to allow income earned within tax-advantaged plans (ie: 401k) to also have tax deferred in the country of residence. Whether that is possible depends on the country of residence and likely some specifics qualifications, but to suggest to the OP that they simply forget about the IRA because it will be useless could be directly detrimental to their overall finances.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon OP explicitly stated "`leaving me some slack for investing in my retirement`.  To me, that means "I'm not going to contribute to a 401(k)."  I guess that needs clarification from OP.

Comment: @RonJohn There are still several factual errors in your answer. Yes, the OP may quite likely owe US taxes on investment income [because you continue to ignore this point - consider as a simple example that dividends are deemed sourced in the country of origination - ie: APPL dividends are first taxable in the US, before the home country]. Yes, there is quite likely a benefit to something like an IRA, depending on the tax treaty between the US and the country of eventual residence. No, 401k accounts are irrelevant, and special consideration should be given to what's currently in those accounts.

Comment: Finally, the assertion that most countries don't have an IRA / 401k type concept, because of 'higher government pensions' is without merit. Most modern tax systems have something very similar to the US 401k / IRA systems. The whole world north of the 49th parallel, south of the Rio Grande, or East of the Eastern Seaboard is not a communist command economy.